# Refer to keys in ansible's hostvars dictionary with a variable names, not strings

Tags: ansible

My `hosts` are defined in one playbook and I'm defining a variable in one host and later attempting to refer to it using `hostvars` in a different host. A simple example that demonstrates what I need:

`topmost.yml` includes two files:

```
[build@localhost ~]$ cat topmost.yml 
- include: top.yml

- include: test.yml
```

`top.yml` defines two variables and calls `add_host` on each of them:

```
[build@localhost ~]$ cat top.yml 
- hosts: all
  name: Define hosts
  connection: local

  vars:
  - webserver: 10.193.219.244
  - nfs: 172.100.139.200

  tasks:

  - name: Add webserver
    add_host:
      hostname: "{{ webserver }}"
      groups: "webserver_host"

  - name: Add nfs server
    add_host:
      hostname: "{{ nfs }}"
      groups: "nfs_server"
```

Finally, in `test.yml`, I would like to create a temporary file (on `webserver_host`) and later use it in the section under `nfs_server`.

```
[build@localhost ~]$ cat test.yml 

 - hosts: webserver_host
  name: Print variables defined earlier
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Create a temporary file
      tempfile:
        state: file
      register: temp_file

    - debug: var=temp_file.path

- hosts: nfs_server
  name: Print variables defined earlier
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    # How should I refer to temp_file.path using a variable??
    - debug: var=hostvars[" {{ webserver }}"]['temp_file']['path']
```

Output from running `topmost.yml`

```
[build@localhost ~]$ ansible-playbook -i 172.100.139.200,10.193.219.244 topmost.yml   
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: 'include' for playbook includes. You should use 'import_playbook' instead. This feature will be removed in version 
2.8. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

PLAY [Define hosts] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.193.219.244]
ok: [172.100.139.200]

TASK [Add webserver] **********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [172.100.139.200]

TASK [Add nfs server] *********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.193.219.244]

PLAY [Print variables defined earlier] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.193.219.244]

TASK [Create a temporary file] ************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.193.219.244]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.193.219.244] => {
    "temp_file.path": "/tmp/ansible.VlvhO5"
}

PLAY [Print variables defined earlier] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [172.100.139.200]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [172.100.139.200]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'webserver' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/build/test.yml': line 18, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - debug: var=hostvars[\" {{ webserver }}\"]['temp_file']['path']\n      ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/build/topmost.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
10.193.219.244             : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   
172.100.139.200            : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `debug` task is syntactically wrong, it should be:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ hostvars[webserver]['temp_file']['path'] }}"
```

Secondly, you defined `webserver` variable in the first play and it is unavailable outside of that play.

You'd need to pass the variable to the in-memory inventory to be able to refer to its value from other plays:

```
name: Add nfs server
add_host:
  hostname: "{{ nfs }}"
  groups: "nfs_server"
  webserver: "{{ webserver }}"
```

Comment: Thanks much for the solution. It is dope.

Answer (score 1):

If the use-case is to configure all hosts an option would be to loop the group *webserver_host*.

```
- hosts: nfs_server
  name: Print variables defined earlier
  tasks:
- debug: var=hostvars["{{ item }}"]['temp_file']['path']
  loop: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['groups']['webserver_host'] }}"
```

.

```
PLAY [Print variables defined earlier]     
*************************************************************************
TASK [debug] 
*************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.13] => (item=None) => {
"hostvars[\"192.168.1.12\"]['temp_file']['path']": "/tmp/ansible.DZIGlA"
}
```